# Angular Material : White color appears in the Background after clicking on Delete Rows from the Table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-dialog

White Color appears in the background of the dialog box:

[image]

TypeScript: config-referrals.component.ts

```
    openDialog(action, obj) {
        this.globalService.configAvailability = null;
        obj.action = action;
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddConsultantComponent,{
          data: obj,
        });
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
          this.ngOnInit();
        });
      }
```

Comment: Please provide some code :)

Comment: @Chaka15 Please check it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript: config-referrals.component.ts

```
    openDialog(action, obj) {
            this.globalService.configAvailability = null;
            obj.action = action;
            const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddConsultantComponent,{
              data: obj,
              scrollStrategy: new NoopScrollStrategy()
            });
            dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
              this.ngOnInit();
            });
          }
```

Comment: I got the solution, and it worked for me.